# Sveltekit static site 404 when returning from external site

Tags: sveltekit

I have a basic static site [here](https://test.kiwiroad.net/).
When I click on the Master Plumbers logo it takes me to their website fine, but if I try to get back to my site it only works if I had clicked through from the index page. Otherwise I get a 404.
It works fine on localhost via `npm run dev`, `npm run preview`, it works fine on [Vercel](https://brightside-svelte.vercel.app/)
The only place it doesn't work is on my host.

Here is my `svelte.config.js` file:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

export default {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            // default options are shown
            pages: 'build',
            assets: 'build',
            fallback: null,
            precompress: false
        }),

        prerender: {
            // This can be false if you're using a fallback (i.e. SPA mode)
            default: true
        }

        
    },
    trailingSlash: 'always',
};
```

And here is the relevant bit of my `__layout.svelte` file:

```
<div class="subtitle">Local. Reliable. Professional.</div>
<br />
<div class="gridContainer">
    <div id="sideMenu" class="col-3">
        <a href="/">About Us</a>
        <a href="/whoweare">Who We Are</a>
        <a href="/services">Our Services</a>
        <a href="/location">Our Location</a>
        <a href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
    </div>

    <div id="mainContent" class="col-6">
        <div class="pageContent">
            <slot />
        </div>
    </div>
```

I don't know if it's any help, but this is what the build folder looks like:

```
images
contact.html
favicon.png
index.html
location.html
services.html
style.css
whoweare.html
_app
```

I've tried messing about with the trailingSlash setting but it doesn't appear to make any difference to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your host is not handling the matching between `/location` and `/location.html` correctly, you can try this by going to this page and refreshing, it will also give a 404, but add `.html` to the url and it works.

How you configure this is out of scope for SvelteKit and depends entirely on your host, but likely you have to mess with a `.htaccess` file